# Dicom Window width & level formula not giving greyvalues

Tags: c#, image, dicom

I'm trying to implement the Window Width and level formula from de Dicom specification in my application. Only it's not returning any grayscales at the moment. The dicom specifies the formula as following:

*These Attributes are applied according to the following pseudo-code, where x is the input value, y
is an output value with a range from ymin to ymax, c is Window Center (0028,1050) and w is
Window Width (0028,1051):*

```
if (x <= c - 0.5 - (w-1)/2), then y = ymin
else if (x > c - 0.5 + (w-1)/2), then y = ymax,
else y = ((x - (c - 0.5)) / (w-1) + 0.5) * (ymax - ymin)+ ymin
```

So i've translated this into the following c# syntax:

```
if (pixelData[i] <= wLevel - 0.5 - (wWidth - 1) / 2)
    oColor = 0;
else if (pixelData[i] > wLevel - 0.5 + (wWidth - 1) / 2)
    oColor = 255;
else
    oColor = (int)((pixelData[i] - (wLevel - 0.5)) / (wWidth - 1) + 0.5) * (255 - 0) + 0;
```

Howevery, the last part of the formula

```
oColor = (int)((pixelData[i] - (wLevel - 0.5)) / (wWidth - 1) + 0.5) * (255 - 0) + 0;
```

Only seems to return 0

[image: Example]

Anyone sees how this is possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The meaning of VOI LUT is to map a given pixel range to displayable values (usually 0..0xFF), using clamping for out of range pixel values.

This means that for a given window/level we can compute the displayable range:

`level-window/2 , level + window/2` .

For pixel values that are in that range, linear transformation is used:

`((pixel - lower_window_limit) / window) * displayable_range`

where `lower_window_limit` is `level - window/2`

This `-window/2` is missing in your formula.

Comment: Okay, hmm only when I change the last part of the code to `oColor = ((pixelData[i] - (wLevel - wWidth / 2)) / wWidth) * 255;` I still get the same result o.O

Comment: Oh god, it had to do with floats being converted to integers. I'm never good with that. I've changed it to the following to make it work: `oColor = ((pixelData[i] - (wLevel - wWidth / 2)) *255) * wWidth;`